# Where to add C-Wire connection for thermostat

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I’d like to ask a follow up question on this thread below.

[How can I add a "C" common wire to this system?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15250/how-can-i-add-a-c-common-wire-to-this-system)

This was the fix: In the wiring diagram in the PDF you linked, the BR (brown) wire connected to the secondary side of the transformer would be your "C" wire. It connects inside the cabinet to the pump and fan relays, and comes out of the cabinet to the A/C condensor control (along with the "y" wire from the thermostat).

In my system I have a white wire connected to the brown wire with a wire nut, not yellow. Would that still be the correct connection to connect the blue c wire to?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds reasonable,

Basically the C wire is the opposite end of the transformer secondary to the R wire.

Comment: That makes sense. Idk if this photo came through on the post or not but this is what I’m working with. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMXgI.jpg

Comment: Yup that's definately a brown wire connected to a white wire. I can't see what any of the wires do,  electricity isn't only about matching colour patterns, where the wire go to and come from matters more.