# How can I add a common "C" wire to my thermostat?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Options for adding “C” wire to thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/options-for-adding-c-wire-to-thermostat)

I recently bought the Honeywell THM5320R Wireless thermostat.  After going to hook it up I found what many others have, it requires a common wire for power.  I looked at some of the other posts on this topic but could use some confirmation.

My HVAC in the attic looks like:

[image]

The items are labeled X R C G W with RCGW going to thermostat. The C connection currently has 2 wires attached, one goes back to the hvac unit itself along with the X wire.  The other appears to run to the outside compressor.  A second wire from the compressor path (red) is connected to a Blue wire that then runs to the thermostat.

A closer view

[image]

If you look at the thermostat you can see that the blue wire then connects to the yellow terminal (compressor stage 1(?)). I assume that (after looking at the wiring diagram) that this is simply a circuit that powers on the outside compressor.

[image]

So I would assume that to get a common wire (only 4 wires in cable) that I would simply need to run an additional wire from the C terminal on the HVAC to the C terminal on the Thermostat? First I would need to verify 24v.

Does this sound correct?