# Zone Controller T-Stat Wiring w/ 24V transformer, isolation relays for 2 zones

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, boiler, zoned-heating

I have a new Navien SmartZone+ 6-Zone Control for my boiler-based heating system.   It is great, except it provides no power on C.

I realize the internet has researched the heck out of adding a C wire.  There are lots of solutions for different situations.

My case is a little different:  I have a 24V transformer and two isolation relays.  They were used previously to provide 2 Nests with C wires, so this worked before... but my plumber disassembled the old zone controller and I'm left a bit baffled by how this worked...

Wiring an isolation relay with a 24-V transformer is well explained by ecobee: [image: here]

But I'm not sure based on [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/how-can-i-use-a-separate-transformer-to-provide-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat) whether the following will work:

1. Split the L side of the 24V transformer and connect it to C for both thermostats and one side of each of the isolation relays
2. Split the N side of the 24V transformer and connect it to R for both thermostats
3. Wire the W from each thermostat back to their respective isolation relays

Do I have this right?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### That is correct, yes

That is a correct way to wire the coil-sides of two isolation relays -- one end of the secondary provides C to the relay coils and thermostat C wires, while the other side of the secondary provides R to the thermostats, and the W wires from the thermostats go to the free terminals on the corresponding relay coils.

The relay contacts then simply go in parallel -- this means that a call for heat from either thermostat will fire the boiler.

Comment: Thanks very much, ThreePhaseEel -- had other emergencies crop up that prevented me from finishing this until yesterday.  Worked like a charm!

Comment: Should the C or Rh wires be fused at all?  I have a similar isolation really setup as above The 24VAC transformer sits behind the a HVAC 15A circuit-breaker. Does the thermo stat need its own fuse protection?

Comment: @Moto_Nomad -- you're better off asking that as its own question