# How can I get my thermostat C wire connected?

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

I have an older furnace, on the switch block I have Y,C.W,R and an unlabeled screw that connects to the shut off it looks like. I need to hook up a thermostat that needs the C wire. I have a spare wire, in the bundle which I hooked up to the c terminal downstairs, from these videos that I've seen it tells me to then bridge the Y and G together, I do not have a G on the block, what do I need to do to get the neutral wire set up

Comment: Forgot to add that I have gas heat only

Comment: What is the make and model of the furnace?

Comment: After more testing I discovered even though its a c wire, it's not pulling 24v, so I'll need to add another 24v to the one wire

Comment: It's only a `C` wire, if it's attached to the `C` terminals at both ends.  It sounds like you're not sure what you're doing, you might want to contact a local HVAC technician before you fry your furnace.

Comment: This [answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33) might be helpful.

Comment: I spoke with honeywell (thermostat), the issue I was having was the thermostat was resetting, while on the phone we found out that the c wire had 0 voltage, and the thermostat as actually pulling the 24v from the rh wire. So I went ou and bought a 24vac power supply to give the thermostat the voltage it needs

Comment: You should only have 24VAC between Rh or Rc and C - C is the neutral and works as a return so the thermostat can be powered without powering any of the other relays

Comment: It's a z wave/wifi thermostat, which requires 24v to rh/rc and the common needs power as well to power the z wave.

Answer (score 2):

You have a C wire, so use it - you don't have to bridge as that is only necessary if you don't have a spare wire.