# Thermostat C-wire replacement using a wall socket?

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have a Filtrete 3M WiFi thermostat. As expected, it takes a C wire, which my apartment doesn't have and the apartment maintenance folks wont' let met wire either.

However, there's a wall socket right next to the thermostat mounting on the wall.

Can someone walk me through what I will need to potentially be able to use the wall socket to power my WiFI module?

The thermostat itself works fine, it is just the WiFi module that doesn't work without the C cable.

Comment: This may help: http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/20635/2196

Comment: When you say "won't let me wire" does that means they won't let you run a new wire (and what makes you think you need to)? Or does it mean they won't let you adjust wiring in the furnace? -- How many conductors do you have in the wire for the thermostat? (Usually it's either 2 or 5). Is this for heat, A/C or both? Single or dual-stage heat? Heat pump? I believe most of the time you see 5-wire now, and with A/C and single-stage heat you only need 4 wires making it easy to change one to a C wire.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect an external power adaptor that provides from 12 to 24 VAC to the C and RH termainals of your thermostat.    [This forum](http://forums.radiothermostat.com/viewforum.php?f=12) has quite a few questions and answers related to that particular thermostat.

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up doing that, and I found the forum very helpful too!