# How do I connect a C-wire on a Triangle Tube Prestige Solo 110?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I purchased a [Honeywell RTH6580WF](http://yourhome.honeywell.com/home/Products/Thermostats/7-Day-Programmable/RTH6580WF.htm) to use with my recently installed [Triangle Tube Prestige Solo 110 propane boiler](http://www.triangletube.com/TriangleTubeProduct.aspx?CatID=1&PID=1). I only have two wires at my existing heat-only thermostat. I understand that the c-wire is common. There is no terminal labeled "C" in the boiler, but all the grounds are to the chassis/terminal block backplane.

The existing connections at the thermostat are `W`, `RH` and a jumper between `RH` and `RC`. I contacted Honeywell customer service, and they said "call a contractor." Can I power the RTH6580WF by simply connecting the `C` in the new thermostat to household common, or do I need to run it back to the chassis or somewhere else of the boiler, or...? If I HAVE to add a separate transformer, where do I connect the + and - from the transformer to the thermostat?

Comment: Have you read [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33)? If you post an image of the boiler wiring diagram (should be in the installation manual and/or inside the unit); or a link to it online, we should be able to show you where to connect the `C` wire.

Comment: @Tester101 I did look at that response, but with no labeled "C" connection on my boiler, I was leery of frying a $999 part. Wiring diagram is on page 31 of [link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=triangle%20tube%20prestige%20solo%20110%20wiring%20diagram&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.triangletube.com%2Fdocuments%2F1%2FPrestige%2520%2520110%2520TriMax%2520Manual%25200313.pdf&ei=jjd6UqLJLeGfyQGQtIGACw&usg=AFQjCNH3hbG2w_jAiokmI9BQK8oRxNm4BQ&bvm=bv.55980276,d.aWM)

Answer (score 0):

The 24V transformer is part of the control board, and so is not shown on the wiring diagram you've linked to. However, `R` is always one side of the transformers secondary, and `C` is always the other side. The thermostat needs to draw its own power, and so requires a connection to "`C`" to complete the circuit.

[image: 24V Transformer]

Your thermostat is just a load on the 24V circuit.

[image: Thermostat on 24V Circuit]

If you don't feel comfortable modifying the wiring, it's probably best to contact a local HVAC technician.