# How to connect thermostat C wire to Weil-McLain CGa boiler?

Tags: boiler, thermostat-c-wire

I have Weil-McLain gas boiler for hot water heat and going to install WiFi thermostat that requires common 24V 'C' wire. I do have a free wire in the cable but cannot figure out where should I connect it on the boiler, there's no any terminal, marked as 'C', 'common' or similar.
The system includes hot water boiler and central AC. Currently I use thermostat with battaries that has 5 wires going in.

Comment: Just a heads up that there's been a suggestion to make a generic question about how to locate the C wire terminal on the HVAC/Boiler the encompass many similar questions. If you'd like to rephrase this question to be more generic, we can use this rather than considering it a dup once the other question is created.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CGa-010 wiring diagram](http://www.weil-mclain.com/en/multimedia-library/pdf/weil-mclain-pdf/wiring-diagrams/cga-010.pdf), you'll want to connect the `C` wire for the thermostat to the terminal pointed to in this image.

[image: CGa-010 Wiring]

Notice the transformer is circled in red. The location where the transformer wiring terminates is circled in orange. The "common" side of the transformers secondary is pointed to by a large blue arrow.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I locate the wire, but didn't connect it yet.

Comment: Is there any difference what transformer use for C in two-transformers system? I have independent boiler and A/C. I'm going to use boiler transformer to power termostat, but doubt if it could influence A/C.

Comment: You'll use the same transformer that supplies the `R` wire to the thermostat.

Comment: I have both Rh from boiler and Rc from A/C.

Comment: You'll pair the `C` from the boiler, with the `R` from the boiler.

Comment: Got it. I just realized that termostat doesn't have Rh, it has R and Rc. Sorry for bothering and thank you again.