# Adding C Wire to thermostat

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I bought a wifi thermostat and tried to use G instead of C since that's what the manufacture suggested if no C. Was able to on the thermostat end but how do I add it on cooling/heating system end. Picture attached. Any help appreciated. I could not find the circuit.

[image: Pic of my boiler]

[image]

Comment: We need photos of the wiring at the system end, and a good shot of the wiring diagram if you can get htat

Comment: It looks like you have a boiler, which means zone valves and/or zone controllers.  We'll have to know about all the equipment involved (including  zone valves, etc).

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/49064/33) might be helpful