# Replacing my Honeywell thermostat with a Nest heatlink in the UK

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, uk

Can someone help with this.
Trying to pick the C wire and the NO wire from here.
Please note I am in the UK

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkr11.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai37q.png]

Comment: C Wire is blue. So use pin 2. https://www.pickhvac.com/thermostat/c-wire/

Comment: Hi.   I am in the UK and the picture shows

Comment: This is UK wiring and the picture shows pin 1 which is the live wire pin 2 is yellow but no idea wht it does. Pin 3 is blue which is the neutral wire here. Pin 4 is the earth/ grounded wire. I was thinking that the C or common wire was the red/ live wire.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I identify the C terminal on my HVAC?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/33593/2196)

Comment: @BMitch -- definitely not a dupe, UK HVAC controls are completely different from their US counterparts

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd pics are identical. Did you intend to upload 3 different pics? If so, please [edit] to include the proper ones.

Comment: Well I have found the serial number of the Hineywell thermostat.... its T6380 as shown in pic2. The C wire is the red wire in pin 1.  The Normally Open wire NO is  the yellow wire in pin 3.