# How to connect a DIY thermostat to the HVAC System

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I am building a DIY thermostat similar to this [blog](http://blog.spark.io/2014/01/17/open-source-thermostat/). I want to connect it to the HVAC system of my home. How do I do that?

I found this [post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat) which is very informative but doesn't completely answer my question.

Comment: It completely depends on the type of system, as well as the make and model of all the components.

Comment: It's best to ask the specific questions you have.  But some quick concepts of a thermostat: you can think of them as automated switches.  Most have a shared hot that they will then use to turn on lines to activate different parts of the HVAC system.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't supplied much detail, I'll have to use nonspecific examples based on typical installation methods.

## Furnace and Condensing unit

If you have a setup where you have a furnace, and an outdoor condensing unit. The wiring will be similar to this (*Note: This is a basic overview, not actual wiring*).

[image: Furnace and Condensing Unit]

Basically, the `R` wire provides power to the thermostat. `W`, `Y` and `G` are energized depending on the state of the thermostat. For example. If the thermostat is set to the `COOL` mode, and the temperature in the room is above the set point. The `Y` and `G` terminals of the thermostat will be energized. This tells the furnace to turn on the blower at high speed, and  the condensing unit to turn on. Alternatively, if the thermostat is set to the `HEAT` mode, and the temperature in the room is below the set point. The `W` terminal will be energized, which tells the furnace to turn on.

## Heat Pump

If you have a heat pump, the wiring will be similar to this.

[image: Heat Pump]

Here the `R` wire again provides power to the thermostat. This type of setup uses either an `O`, `B`, or `O/B` terminals to change the state of the reversing valve in the heat pump. In this type of setup, the thermostat works similar to the example above, though it also has to manage an extra terminal.

Some thermostats offer both an `O` and a `B` terminal.

[image: Thermostat O and B]

When the thermostat is in `COOL` mode and calls for cool, the `O` terminal will be energized. If you have a system where the reversing valve is normally in `HEAT` mode, you'll use the `O` terminal to move the reversing valve to `COOL` mode.  When the thermostat is in `HEAT` mode and calls for heat, the `B` terminal will be energized. If you have a system where the reversing valve is normally in `COOL` mode, you'll use the `B` terminal to move the reversing valve to `HEAT` mode.

Some thermostats offer and `O/B` terminal, and will have a jumper to select which function it provides.

[image: Thermostat O/B]

In this case, you'll set the jumper based on the type of system you have. Then when the thermostat calls for heat or cool, the `O/B` terminal will be energized appropriately.

For more information on the `C` terminal, please see [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33).