# Where do I connect a C wire in a Rheem Furnace REAB 1415J?

Tags: wiring, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I'm upgrading the thermostat with a Honeywell wifi one. I found all cables at the thermostat end, but can't figure out where to connect the C wire to the furnace (Rheem REAB 1415J).

[image: Wiring Diagram]

Comment: Do any of the other questions on the site regarding the C-wire help (there are quite a few)? If not, how is your problem different? A photograph of the wiring and the wiring diagram would also help.

Comment: Can you identify the 24VAC transformer?  One wire coming from it will go to the same place the "red" wire on the thermostat, and the other will be what you need for the C wire.  There are plenty of C-wire questions to help once you find the transformer and associated connections.

Comment: Is there a schematic printed inside the unit? If so, can you post a clear photo of it?

Comment: Can you get us a better photo of the schematic?

Answer (score 0):

In thermostat wiring, C stands for Common. Look for a terminal labeled Com, which is another abbreviation for common.

I did not look up your thermostat, however it is likely that it needs the common wire to work properly. Many thermostats don't really need a common wire but it is almost always recommended to have one especially with these "smarter" thermostats. More information about the common terminal can be found [here](http://smartthermostatguide.com/thermostat-c-wire-explained/) and [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat). Some thermostats have a couple of batteries that they can run off of instead of using the common but that would likely not include a wifi enabled one because it uses more power than a simple programmable model.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

C is the unswitched line from the transformer. 2 wires come from the transformer, look for the one that connects direcctly to one side of every load and find its terminal. The switched line is the other line from the transformer and goes to all the controls. Most systems use C. Trane/ American Std use B.