# Can I use the unused blue wire as a C wire?

Tags: electrical, wiring, air-conditioning, thermostat-c-wire

I'm installing a wifi-capable thermostat in my house which for obvious reasons requires a C wire. The old school mercury thermostat I'm replacing didnt have a C wire connected but I've checked the furnace schematic and connections and the C is there.

Can someone please take a look at the attachments and verify that the C wire exists / that I'm not losing my mind?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are some additional pics: 
[http://m.imgur.com/gallery/u1QJQ](https://m.imgur.com/gallery/u1QJQ)

It looks like I should be able to add the unused blue wire to the C terminal on the furnace. Thoughts?

I've been referencing this post: [How can I add a "C" wire to my thermostat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Connect the unused blue wire to the `C` terminal in the furnace, then connect the other end to the `C` terminal on the thermostat.  As long as there's no funny business between the furnace and the thermostat, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you.  This is a mess.  They've reused symbols in a way I don't like.

Here's NOT your C-wire:  the five-wire harness and white connector labeled 4-3-2-1-C.  (in your first picture) That appears to be a motor drive and is probably 120VAC. That would make a big bang.

I think this is your C wire:  The schematic (second picture) shows a group of terminals labeled R-Gh-W-Gc-Y-C. (bottom area, left edge). (They are fed off a transformer just as you'd expect R and C to be.  C is connected internally as you'd expect.) Look for a cluster of six terminals with exactly those labels. It may be those terminals on the top edge of your top photo.

Comment: Using the blue wire worked perfectly. Thanks!