# Why isn't the "C" or Common wire working on my Nest thermostat?

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

I Have connected the Blue wire to the `C` terminal on a 3rd Generation Nest and to the Blue wires on the Transformer....... But the Nest Thermostat does not show the Blue wire connected on the Equipment Detected Page of the Nest Thermostat.

The Problem is the Heater Has Short Cycles when heating. Nest support folks say a `C` wire is needed.

Help Needed  !!!!!!!

Comment: Old Goodman Heater

Comment: Do you need help with how to run more wires or is your question why the blue wire you connected not working?

Comment: Thanks  Why the Blue wire when connected is not working ????

Comment: What model is your heater?  Can you measure 24VAC across R and C at the Nest?

Comment: I am away for a few days, I will measure the voltage and post ASAP.Check back in a few days,

Comment: Thanks
So Nest needs two 24 Volt supplies,one on RC/RH and one on the C Terminal is what your telling me. Nest support is telling me a wire needs to go between the C terminal of the nest and the Common side of the AC side of the system.[Does not work]. Do I need a second 24 Volt Transformer ????? Nest would like me to hire a HVAC contractor.I am just a Homeowner with DYI preference. Thank

Comment: @EdJPanco Read through [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/33), it should at least help you understand what the C wire is.

Comment: Goodman  Model Numbers 100.000 BTU 92% GMNT-100-4 & a 36,000 12 SEER CLJ36-1

Answer (score 2):

The Nest is colorblind.  It has no idea what color **your** wires are.  The cutesy little Nest screen will show wire colors, but it's wild-guessing based on commonly used wire colors.  *In this example, the W wire might actually be brown, the G could be orange.*

[image]

*The wire colors on the display mean nothing.*

There is no official color code for the `C` wire, since it wasn't traditionally used in thermostats.  You can use any color, as long as that wire isn't being used for something else.

The essential thing is that the `C` wire connects to the 24V side of the transformer, on the terminal *which is not* the one the `R` wire goes to.

*Connecting C and R to the same terminal of the transformer would do nothing, and the Nest display would probably show C as not connected.*

Whatever the Nest display is indicating about the "Blue" wire is irrelevant.  It doesn't know or care what color you are using for the `C` wire.  Blue is not an official color for the `C` wire, actually Blue and `B` are commonly used to switch a heat pump from heat mode to cool mode.  If you don't have a heat pump and the wire color is unused in your cable, steal it for `C`.

See also [Nest's page](https://nest.com/support/article/Should-my-B-wire-go-in-Nest-s-O-B-connector-Or-is-it-a-common-wire-that-belongs-in-the-C-connector).