# Problem connection C wire into Lennox Furnace

Tags: hvac

I would like to connect my new Honeywell WiFi thermostat (RTH6580WF1001) to a Lennox Elite dual Heater and Cooler system.
I don’t have a C wire in my old thermostat. I have read online that I can connect the G wire into the C terminal, at the thermostat and heater cooler system. In the terminal block I already have a wire connected (see photo) in the C terminal, Is it OK if connect the G wire in the same in the C terminal given that there is already a red wire in the C terminal at the furnace?  thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your unit has a "C" wire connection and a wire attached.  Why don't you do the obvious thing and connect the "C" wire to the "C" terminal on the thermostat and the "G" wire to the "G" terminal?

Comment: @jwh20 look closer. The wire attached to the C terminal is one of a 2-wire cable, and probably runs to the compressor outside and not to the thermostat.

Comment: @brhans or it could be like my setup where the installer must have had only 4 conductor wire and used two 4's to make a 6.  But regardless, the "C" terminal is there and it should be used.

Comment: there is no C wire coming out at the thermostat end. see new photo attached. Is it OK if connect the G wire in the same in the C terminal given that there is already a red wire in the C terminal at the furnace?

Comment: Well, the good news is that "C IS OPTIONAL WITH BATTERIES".

Comment: The problem is you only have 4 wires running between your furnace and the thermostat and you need all 4.  You can't just change where the G wire goes - that controls the fan.  There are kits to "add" a C-wire when you physically do not have one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a "C" wire to my thermostat?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat)