# HVAC adding C wire to older system w/ wire nuts

Tags: hvac

I have an older system, separate AC and gas heat. Trying to add a C wire. All existing wires are connected outside the air handler with wire nuts. I've unwrapped an unused blue in the lower right of the picture; that runs to the thermostat. As you can see, the other wires in that cable are yellow joined to red from a different cable, green joined to thick green, and red joined to white from a different cable. I believe I can add that blue to one of them - I'm guessing add it to the green/green wire nut? Thanks for any advice[image]

Comment: Without knowing what terminals the respective wires connect to inside the equipment, any answer is basically going to be a guess.

Comment: Green is supposedly fan, but only if that's what it's actually hooked to. If you could use it there, you wouldn't need another wire in the thermostat cable, since it's already in the thermostat cable.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram posted on the air handler please?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat