# Where to connect the C Wire? See pictures and diagram

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have Rheem RBHC-14A00NFA AC unit. I am trying to install nest thermostat but don’t know where to connect the C wire. I am attaching the picture of the wires and the diagram. Please help! Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: try following instructions https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/37594

Answer (score 0):

There is a very elaborate answer to your question in this post:

[C -wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10527/37594)

Comment: Thank you! I will go over it! I didn’t come across this when searching.

Comment: @scottmeyer we accept payment for our work in form of upvoting and accepting the answers :

Comment: the app doesn’t allow me to upvote nor accept answers. Am I supposed to visit a certain setting or page?

Answer (score 0):

### It's the thick brown wire in the bottom wiring compartment

According to your unit's wiring diagram, your C wire should be a brown wire "tail" in the bottom wiring compartment, and while I can't precisely make out what it's wired to right now, it does appear to be present and connected into the existing condenser wiring, which is a good sign that it is indeed the C wire.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you!

Comment: @scottmeyer -- we thank people around here by upvoting and accepting their answers :)